# typescript error using google.maps - 'google' is not defined

Tags: typescript, google-maps, build, react-app-rewired

I have the following in package.json

```
"@types/google.maps": "~3.48.3",
```

// in my tsx file the first line at the top is

```
/// <reference types='google.maps' />
```

But on accessing google.maps.MapMouseEvent - I get the error 'google' is not defined.
Line 980:43:  'google' is not defined                    no-undef

Line 980 is

```
onMarkerDragEnd = async (mapMouseEvent: google.maps.MapMouseEvent) => {
```

// I also tried

```
/// <reference path='../../../../node_modules/@types/google.maps' />
```

// I also tried in tsconfig.json

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "google.maps"
    ]
  }
```

But the error persists.  I am compiling the typescript using

```
react-app-rewired build
```

Looking for any tips on how to use the @types/google.maps in typescript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`no-undef` is actually an eslint error which can be fixed with https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-globals

```
{
    "globals": {
        "google": "readonly"
    }
}
```

With recent versions of typescript you shouldn't need anything other than the following in your package.json.

```
  devDependencies: {"@types/google.maps": ...}
```

Install with:

```
npm install -D @types/google.maps
```

No triple slash reference, no imports, no compilerOptions.types.

See https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/googlemaps/js-samples/tree/sample-marker-simple for an example.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any value to keep using eslint if typescript is being used?

Comment: Need to specify `google` in both as they do not overlap.

Comment: Solve this by running 'yarn add @types/google.maps'.

Comment: In which file exactly do you add the "globals" object? Even the eslint guide doesn't say.